# Model Binding on dynamic created DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

**Model1:**

```
public class Model1
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }  
            public int VariantId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }    
            public string Language { get; set; }
            public IList<Model2>  ListModel2{ get; set; }   

            public VmSysVariantResource()
            {              
                ListModel2=new List<Model2>();    
            }
        }
```

**Model2:**

```
public class Model2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParamterId { get; set; }
        public int ValueId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
        public string ParameterName { get; set; }
        public IList<PossibleValue> Values { get; set; }

        public IList<SelectListItem> ValuesSelectListItem
        {
            get
            {

                var list = (from item in Values
                            select new SelectListItem()
                            {
                                Text = item.ValueName,
                                Value = item.Id
                            }).ToList();
                return list;
            }
            set { }
        } 

    }
```

**PossibleValue:**

```
 public class PossibleValue
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ValueName { get; set; }  

    }
```

Now explication about what I want to do:
Suppose we have one Model "Model1". This model have a list of Model2 .
Model2 contains ParameterName and a list of possibleValues.
Now I have form like this:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", null,
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST"
        }))
    {

        <table class="sample" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 400px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Resource.Name:
                </td>
                <td>    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Name) 
                </td>
            </tr>            

            @foreach (var item in Model.ParamtersToValue)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.Parameter:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("ParamtersToValue", @item.ValuesSelectListItem)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    }
```

On post method in controller I want to get Model1 with List of ListModel2.
This is my post method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MyAction(Model1 obj)
        {  }
```

I was expected to get on post method Model1 with ListModel2 that will contain SelectedValue chosen from dropdown, but I am not shure how to construct dropdown inside foreach block to enforce model binding to work.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default model binder works with indexes. So, to have it model bind, change your `foreach` loop to a `for` loop and render the control with an index. Like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ParamtersToValue.Count; i++) {
    @* .. stuff here *@

    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.ParametersToValue[i], Model.ParametersToValue[i].ValuesSelectListItem)
    </td>

    @* .. stuff here *@
}
```

This will result in element names such as `[0].ParametersToValue`, `[1].ParametersToValue`, etc. The model binder will bind them in order of appearance into an enumerable of your choice.